Will Async HTTP request resolve server timeout?
I've got server A that sends request to server B using CloseableHttpClient's execute method.
When server B proceeds with the request it tries to send request to server A(before returning the response) using RestTemplate's postForEntity. And I get timeout exception on Server A (I guess it's because of some sort of circular dependency in terms of requests). So will introducing the AsyncRestTemplate postFroEntity on server B resolve this issue ?
To explain why I need such a logic, I need to call Server A endpoint from Server B to write data in the database of server A that the process on server B has indeed started.
I thought about using Async requests on both ends, Server A that calls Server B, and on Server B that in the middle of a process calls Server A. But won't this lead to some sort of data inconsistency? And I guess the solution for my question will be the usage of Kafka or RabbitMQ, but maybe there is more simpler way of solving my problem?
Here are some code snippets to further explain further:
Server A:
try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault()) {

    log.info("******* start outBoundDocument URL: " + DATA_CENTER_URL + "/rest/api/outbound-documents");
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(DATA_CENTER_URL + "/rest/api/outbound-documents");
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "UTF-8");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    // Add the hostname as a custom header
    httpPost.setHeader("X-Sender-Host", SYNERGY_URL);

    UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new 
    UsernamePasswordCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    httpPost.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(credentials, httpPost, null));

    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(document);
    log.info("******** outBoundDocument send JSON=" + json);
    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);// here we request Server B

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                byte[] bytes = 
        IOUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity().getContent());
                log.error("******** outBoundDocument " + new 
        String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    }

} catch (IOException | AuthenticationException e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}


Server B:
// some received DTO manipulations:

// here we call for Server A to write in it's DB that process on Server B has started
ResponseEntity<ErrorInfoDto> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(
                fullUrl,// basically the host:port and endpoint to server A
                logRecord,
                ErrorInfoDto.class
);
putOutboundDocument(docOutgoing);// sends SOAP request
return new OkDto();



It's impossible to answer about how your system is or should be behaving without far more detail than you have provided.  In fact, I don't see how you would provide enough information in the SO format, so if we're to help you, you'll have to first help us by breaking down the problem into a much narrower question that you can support with relevant code.  Or maybe more than one such question.

A sends a request to B and while processing this request, B sends request back to A? I would question such design

Yeah, agree about poor design, but that what I've been asked to do

I see you added some code, but it doesn't capture many of the details needed to inform an answer.  Again, I don't think you can capture enough detail in the SO format for a question such as you have posed.  You'll need to drill down and focus on something much mode specific (supposing that your efforts to do so don't lead you to discover your own answer).

Generally speaking, however, application servers suitable for running a framework such as Spring are mutlithreaded.  That the message pattern in your system goes A --> B --> A is not inherently problematic for such a system in the sense that one would expect it to deadlock.  Thus, it seems unlikely that making one or both of the requests asynchronous would solve the problem.  It's more likely either that the initial and loopback requests to application A both need to lock some underlying resource, or perhaps that you are getting an infinite loop of requests.

Won't this behavior A->B->A lead to a deadlock itself? A waits for a response from B, while B waits for a response from A, thus the timeout exception on A. Thats's what I think, but maybe I don't clearly understand the behavior of the CloseableHttpClient and RestTemplate. And if my theory is incorrect I've got no idea what can possibly cause timeout on A, since it happens only when I send request from B to A (if I remove this part it's fine)

Apart from the question on design, what exact operation is causing timeout? Is it the first operation on service B or second operation on service A? Have you tried checking the consumed time on both operations?

@user27424299, "Won't this behavior A->B->A lead to a deadlock itself?" -- no, not inherently, as I already told you.  Application servers can (in general) handle multiple requests concurrently, such as the initial request from client to A concurrently with the resulting request from B to A.  Additionally, the HTTP(S) request from A to B will be over a separate connection from the request from B back to A.  There is no issue inherent in having multiple connections between the same two endpoint at the same time.
